# Compiling Java for Android Apps

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am developing a mobile application with Cordova(phonegap) for Android.

I was asked by my client, to provide the Java library to him, to develop his own app.

I want to know what is the best way to provide him with the Java code that he can use in his app BUT making sure he does not have access to my code (source code).

How can i take the Java code I am using in phonegap and give it to him as a library.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail, but in general, the same way as always: as a jar.

Comment: but can't someone decompile a jar a file too? @chrylis

Comment: Is Obfuscation Jar files is the last and only option?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

The closest thing your going to be able to get to not providing the client your code is to restrict all access modifiers as much as you can and send the client an obfuscated Jar file.

Ultimately though, since you seem to believe that the client will violate any license you provide with your code, all the client would have to do is use Fernflower to decompile the Jar, change all access permissions to public and unobfuscate the code as needed.  This kind of thing is not a capability of Java, obfuscation is the closest thing to limiting code access besides just not giving out the code.

Usually this is circumvented by providing a service which cannot be replaced, such as multplayer in video games, but this does not seem to be applicable.